# SQL: Joining two table based on certain description

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

[image: Two table]

And I want to add GTIN from table 2 to table 1 based on brand name. Though I cant use = or like because as you see in highlighted row they are not fully matched.

For example

Second row in table 1, suppose to have first GTIN from table 2 because both are Ziagen 300mg tablet. However all of what I tried failed to match all row correctly.

Comment: There's definitely nothing in SQL standard for doing this. Different RDBM products do have different custom thing though.

Comment: Have you tried using joins?

Comment: honestly there is not a good way to do this programatically. if the descriptions in each table are constant, you could create a mapping table which maps one description to the other, then join through that table. If the descriptions are not consistent, there really is not a good way.

Comment: @jeremy Kindly can you explain to me what to do you mean by mapping table?

Comment: a table that exists just to relate one thing to another. for example, if you had a table with 2 columns in it consisting of the distinct values that you know match. for example in column one you have "ziagen 300mg tablets" and in column 2 you have ziagen 300mg tab". if you join the 3 tables together, then you'll be able to correlate the records in table one to the records in table 2 by having a "map" of which values match. hope this makes sense

Comment: @Jeremy I was just thinking something similar. A table that holds all the brand names could be used to join the descriptions using wildcards: LIKE '%Brand%'

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Thank a lot. I was doing what you were suggesting by matching brand manually but it consumes time since table contains around 15000 record.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres has a `pg_trgm` module described [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html). Start with a `cross join` joining both tables and calculate the `similarity(t1.brand,t2.brand)` function, which returns the real number.

Next filter the results based on some heuristic number. Then narrow down with choosing single best match using `row_number()` window function.

The results might be not accurate, you could improve it by taking generic similarity into account as well.

```sql
with cross_similarity(generic1,brand1,gtin,brand2,generic2,sim) as (
    select *, similarity(t1.brand, t2.brand) as sim
    from t1,
         t2
    where similarity(t1.brand, t2.brand) > 0
)
, max_similarity as (
    select *, 
      row_number() over (partition by gtin order by sim desc) as best_match_rank
    from cross_similarity
)
select * from max_similarity where best_match_rank =1;
```